# c++ misunderstanding of binomial coeficient recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, binomial-coefficients

code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int binomialCoeff(int n, int k)
{
  // Base Cases
  if (k==0 || k==n)
    return 1;
 else
  return  binomialCoeff(n-1, k-1) + binomialCoeff(n-1, k);
}
int main()
{
    int n = 5, k = 2;
    printf("Value of C(%d, %d) is %d ", n, k, binomialCoeff(n, k));
    return 0;
}
```

I think I can understand the base case. When we use 0 for n and k=n the result is 0!/0! which is = 1. So we return 1. [Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnvTB.png)

But I can't understand this part of the code:

```
 return  binomialCoeff(n-1, k-1) + binomialCoeff(n-1, k);
```

With values of 5 for n and 2 for k I get the result 10. (When replace in the formula).[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnvTB.png)
But why we use аddition?

And one more thing. Why the program doesn't work when I set "n" and "k" from the keyboard?
Like this:

```
int main()
{
    int n,k;
    cin>>n;
    cin>>k;
    printf("Value of C(%d, %d) is %d ", n, k, binomialCoeff(n, k));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the properties of binomial coefficients is that:
C(n, k) can be written as C(n-1,k-1) + C(n-1,k) for all 1 <= k <= n-1.

So a C(3,2) = C(2,1) + C(2,2)
        Or 3  = 2 + 1

This is what is used in the simple recursion example you have shared.

Regarding your second problem, not sure why you should have any problems.

Comment: Thank you. Now it seems clear. So, this formula "C(n-1,k-1) + C(n-1,k)" is the same with the formula in my post.

Comment: Great. If you think any of the above responses have helped you understand the problem, you can close this review with the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

> But why we use аddition?

It's rather question of Maths than programming, there is well known [recursive formula for binomial coefficient calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Recursive_formula). And exactly this formula is used in your program.

> Why the program does't work when i set "n" and "k" from the keyboard

The code looks correct excepting that you use std::istream for input and printf for output. What exactly doesn't work? Do you enter n >= k?

Comment: "Do you enter n >= k?" Yes. My bad. I've entered 2 for n and 5 for k. That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`return  binomialCoeff(n-1, k-1) + binomialCoeff(n-1, k);`

Remember [Pascal Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle)? It uses exactly this recurrence formula with addition.

However I can see you are not building this triangle, but just recursively try to calculate some of the binomial coefficients again and again while using recursion. Memorizing already calculated result may drastically improve your program performance. It might be the case for your second question:

> Why the program does't work when i set "n" and "k" from the keyboard. like this:

It should work but it might take a long time your program to finish if you input rather big `n` and `k`. Running time complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>). With `n > 30` you may notice that execution time is long.